# Bespoke iPhone Application Deployment

Tags: iphone

I am making an iPhone app for a company but I don't want it to be available for download to everybody (like apps in the app store) What is the best way to ensure only set users can download the app?

I was thinking maybe of having some website where users login and can click on a link to download and install the app, but I was told this is not possible. You can only download on the app store...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "iOS Enterprise Distribution". See http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative to iPhone Enterprise distribution (which has its own set of rules and requirements) is to allow download from the app store but require a login in the app to use. Much like HBO-Go. You can't use HBO Go on the iPad unless you have an account with a certain cable provider which has an agreement with HBO. For example, I get HBO at home but can't use the HBO app because my cable company doesn't have an agreement in place for me to use the app so while I can download it I can't do anything with it.

Without knowing your reasons for blocking app downloads I'm not sure if this is a viable solution for you.